# Objective c: passing an NSTimer with a button

Tags: objective-c, timer, uibutton

How do I pass an NSTimer I have declared as timer down to a method being called by a button?

[stickfig addtarget:self action:@selector(tapfig:andtime:) forcontrolevents:uicontroleventtouchupinside];

Sorry about the formatting. I had to ask this on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can not the action: will only send the button itself. Inside the class you may want to store the values inside of an NSDictionary. You can tag the buttons and use the tags as a NSNumber for the key of the dictionary.

Ex.

```
...
//Tag buttons
button1.tag = 1;
button2.tag = 2;
button3.tag = 3;
//Add timers to dictionary
[mutableDictionary setObject:button1Timer forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:button1.tag]];
...

//Action for buttons
-(void)tapfig:(id)sender
{
   NSTimer *timer = [mutableDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:((UIButton*)sender).tag]];
}
```